# MVC 3: Conditionally Adding the Disabled Attribute with the HtmlHelpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have an ASP.Net MVC 3 web application and I am adding a check box to a view page using the HtmlHelper class, like this...

```
@Html.CheckBox("CheckBox1", true, new { @class = "Class1" })
```

What I want to do is conditionally add the disabled attribute based on a view state property. Basically the following would be ideal...

```
@Html.CheckBox("CheckBox1", true, new { @class = "Class1", @disabled = Model.ReadOnly })
```

Unfortunately, due to the nature of the disabled attribute, this will not work because ***any*** value assigned to the disabled attribute (even "false") will be translated as true.

I have already thought of a few solutions to get round this problem, so the question is not how can I do this. But rather, is there a simple way like the desired method above? or do I have to resort to one of the following?..

What I know I could do...

1. Create an if/else statement and write to different `Html.CheckBox` lines (not great for readability - and possible with throw a mark-up warning - not sure)
2. Skip the HtmlHelper class and hand write the tag allowing for better conditionally attributes (keeps the code shorter, but adds inconsistency)
3. Create a custom helper that takes a "disabled" parameter (the cleanest solution, but requires undesired extra methods - probably the best option so far though)

Comment: Have a look at my answer here (uses the 3rd approach you listed): http://stackoverflow.com/a/43131930/6680521

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set disable attribute based on a condition for Html.TextBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660146/set-disable-attribute-based-on-a-condition-for-html-textboxfor)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Define this somewhere in your view/helpers

```
@functions {
 object getHtmlAttributes (bool ReadOnly, string CssClass) 
 {
     if (ReadOnly) {
         return new { @class = CssClass, @readonly = "readonly" };
     }
     return new { @class = CssClass };
 }
}
```

Then use :

```
@Html.TextBox("name", "value", @getHtmlAttributes(Model.ReadOnly, "test"))
```

Comment: Good answer. I had ended up doing the same logic except with a single line (ternary, I think) condition as part of the Html.CheckBox call. Your solution is much nicer, thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks, for information, I suspect that the better way is to define an EditorTemplate for the model, defining the function internally and providing also some sort of client side jQuery magic for doing everything. For example on the Load event of a containing DIV.

Comment: mmm.. the above example doesn't work when I use it with .TextBoxFor() (Instead of .TextBox() ) - Anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name or member access expression...

Comment: How you do the same for add `disable` optionally ?

Comment: Just add a bool parameter to the function and set the value of @readonly accordingly. I've lost contact with .NET MVC so don't really know if this answer still applies with latest version (I hope they've added some better way to do this).

Answer (score 34):

Here's my answer from this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13922813/495000

---

I created the following Helper - it takes a boolean and an anonymous object. If disabled is true, it adds the disabled attribute to the anonymous object (which is actually a Dictionary) with the value "disabled", otherwise it doesn't add the property at all.

```
public static RouteValueDictionary ConditionalDisable(
   bool disabled, 
   object htmlAttributes = null)
{
   var dictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

   if (disabled)
      dictionary.Add("disabled", "disabled");

   return dictionary;
}
```

An example of it in action:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty,    
   HtmlHelpers.ConditionalDisable(true, new { @class = "someClass"))
```

One huge advantage to this approach for me was that it works with virtually all of the MVC HtmlHelpers since they all have Overloads that accept a RouteValueDictionary instead of an anonymous object.

**Caveats**:
`HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes()` uses some fancy code ninja work to get things done. I'm not entirely sure how performant it is... but it's been sufficient for what I use it for. Your mileage may vary.

I don't especially like the name of it - but I couldn't come up with anything better. Renaming is easy.

I also don't love the usage syntax - but again I couldn't come up with anything better. It shouldn't be difficult to change. An extension method on object is one idea... you'd end up with `new { @class = "someClass" }.ConditionalDisable(true)` but then if you only want the disable attribute and don't have anything additional to add you end up with something gross like `new {}.ConditionalDisable(true);` and you also end up with an extension method that shows up for all `object`... which is probably not desirable.

Comment: A most elegant solution. This is the best I have found. I considered an extension method before but it would just be far too general.

Comment: This is a great solution, but I can't seem to get it to work with a Html.ActionLink

Comment: Good solution but it does not work with Html.EditorFor as well

Answer (score 14):

If you want more terse syntax without requiring a helper function, you could use a ternary statement when defining the dictionary used for the html attributes of the @HTML.Checkbox helper...

```
@Html.CheckBox("CheckBox1", true, Model.ReadOnly 
       ? new { @class = "Class1", @disabled = Model.ReadOnly } 
       : null)
```

In this case is Model.ReadOnly is false, null gets passed as the dictionary of html attributes.

Comment: This could get quite verbose if you are setting other attributes.

Comment: @ScottE couldn't you then just setup a property on your view[model] that does all the heavy calculations for you? Then in the cshtml, it's as simple as the example above.

Comment: This doesn't work if you still want to set the @class property in the false condition.

Comment: This does not work. I just tried it with `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FileType, (SelectList)ViewData["FileTypes"], "...", new { @class = "custom-select chosen-select col-md-2", @disabled = canEdit ? null : "disabled"})`, and I get a disabled attribute without value like `<select class="..." disabled id="FileType"><option value="">1st option</option>...</select>`

Answer (score 5):

What do you think about my *simple* solution? It works easily with both possible `HtmlAttributes` types:

- `Dictionary<string, object>`
- `Anonymous Object`:

**First** add the following simple `extension class` to your project:

```
public static class HtmlAttributesExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, object> AddHtmlAttrItem(this object obj, string name, object value, bool condition)
    {
        var items= !condition ? new RouteValueDictionary(obj) : new RouteValueDictionary(obj) {{name, value}};
        return UnderlineToDashInDictionaryKeys(items);
    }
    public static IDictionary<string, object> AddHtmlAttrItem(this IDictionary<string, object> dictSource, string name, object value, bool condition)
    {
        if (!condition)
            return dictSource;

        dictSource.Add(name, value);
        return UnderlineToDashInDictionaryKeys(dictSource);
    }
    private static IDictionary<string, object> UnderlineToDashInDictionaryKeys(IDictionary<string,object> items)
    {
        var newItems = new RouteValueDictionary();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            newItems.Add(item.Key.Replace("_", "-"), item.Value);
        }
        return newItems;
    }
}
```

---

**Now in View:**

**Example1** *(`HtmlAttributes` type as `Anonymous Object`)*

```
@{
  var hasDisabled=true; 
}

@Html.CheckBox("CheckBox1"
              , true
              , new { @class = "Class1"}
               .AddHtmlAttrItem("disabled", "disabled", hasDisabled))
.
```

**Example 2** *(`HtmlAttributes` type as `Dictionary<string, object>`)*

```
@Html.CheckBox("CheckBox1"
              , true
              , new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "Class1" }
               .AddHtmlAttrItem("disabled", "disabled", hasDisabled))
.
```

> Now just change the `hasDisabled` value to `true` or `false`!

---

**Example3** *(Multiple conditional properties)*

```
@{
  var hasDisabled=true;
  var hasMax=false ;
  var hasMin=true ;
}

@Html.CheckBox("CheckBox1"
              , true
              , new { @class = "Class1"}
               .AddHtmlAttrItem("disabled", "disabled", hasDisabled)
               .AddHtmlAttrItem("data-max", "100", hasMax)
               .AddHtmlAttrItem("data-min", "50", hasMin))
.
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! One comment though: I recommend using `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes` instead of `UnderlineToDashInDictionaryKeys` because it's already built-in. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Performing the addition of the disabled attribute client side works for me. Note you should check which fields are allowed to be edited server side, but that is true for where the disabled attribute is declared decoratively also.

In this example I have disabled all childeren of a form using jQuery.

```
    if (Model.CanEdit)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#editForm *').attr('disabled', true);
            });

        </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FieldName, Html.FixBoolAttributes(new {
    @class = "myClass",
    @readonly = myFlag  
}))


public static class BooleanAttributeFix
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Normalises HTML boolean attributes so that readonly=true becomes readonly="readonly" and
    /// readonly=false removes the attribute completely.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlHelper"></param>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static RouteValueDictionary FixBoolAttributes(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var attrs = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        foreach(var attrName in new[] { "disabled", "readonly" })
        {
            object value;
            if(attrs.TryGetValue(attrName, out value))
            {
                if(isTruthy(value))
                {
                    // Change from readonly="true" to readonly="readonly"
                    attrs[attrName] = attrName; 
                }
                else
                {
                    // Remove attribute entirely
                    attrs.Remove(attrName); 
                }
            }
        }
        return attrs;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Apply similar loose rules like javascript does for whether a value is true or not.
    /// e.g. 1 = true, non-empty string = true and so on.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="val"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool isTruthy(object val)
    {   
        if(val == null)
            return false;

        if(val is string)
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)val);
        }

        Type t = val.GetType();

        if(t.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) == null)
        {
            // If a non-nullable value type such as int we want to check for the
            // default value e.g. 0.
            object defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

            // Use .Equals to compare the values rather than == as we want to compare
            // the values rather than the boxing objects.
            // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205029/comparing-boxed-value-types
            return !val.Equals(defaultValue);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked @gb2d answer, here it is in JS using getElementsByClassName taken from here
[getElementByClass().setAttribute doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565909/getelementbyclass-setattribute-doesnt-work)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list, index;
    list = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
    for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
        list[index].setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the top two answers are valid and solve the problem, but a different style which more successfully retains the original/traditional format (lowering the learning curve in team environments);

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = Model.IsReadOnly }.RemoveFalseyAttributes())`

The helper method is a static class which is included in the `_ViewImports.cshtml` and in this vien will only appear in your intellisense when working on views.

The method itself removes the `disabled` attribute if it is false and can be extended to check other attribute easily.

```
public static class ViewUtility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes attributes which when set to false should not be included on the HTML attribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlAttributes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IDictionary<string, object> RemoveFalseyAttributes(this object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
        var attributeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var kvp in routeValueDictionary)
        {
            if (kvp.Key == "disabled" && kvp.Value.Equals(false))
            {
                continue;
            }
            attributeDictionary.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }

        return attributeDictionary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.checkbox?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2#system-web-webpages-html-htmlhelper-checkbox(system-string-system-boolean-system-collections-generic-idictionary((system-string-system-object)))) of `Html.CheckBox()` accpets an `IDictionary<string, object>`, so conditionally adding the `disabled` attribute is achieved with:

```
 @{
     IDictionary<string, object> attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     if (Model.ReadOnly)
     {
         attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
     }
 }

@Html.CheckBox("nameAttribute", Model.IsChecked, attributes)
```