# How to set disable attribute for Html.TextBoxFor based on a property value associated to that textbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I tried using this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086104/mvc3-conditionally-disable-html-textboxfor) like this

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyList[0].FirstName, model.MyList[0].IsEnabled ? (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { })%>
```

but that gave me an error

> "The name model doesn't exist in the current context"

Is there a way to do this in vanilla asp.net MVC 3 without using an if else condition?

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this: I should use the actual model I am passing in to the view. Notice the change in Caps on the second parameter.

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyList[0].FirstName, Model.MyList[0].IsEnabled ? (object)new { disabled = "disabled" } : new { })%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just quickly checking for this error message suggests that maybe your web.config is broken.

[The name 'model' does not exist in current context in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389055/the-name-model-does-not-exist-in-current-context-in-mvc3)

Comment: Fair enough. My second guess would be the model/Model capitalisation, that's caught be out more than once.