# MVC EditorFor Optionally ReadOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates, readonly-attribute

Yesterday, after extensive testing, I got the following to optionally apply the readonly attribute to a control based on the value of `ViewBag.CanEdit`;

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = (ViewBag.CanEdit == true ? Html.Raw("") : Html.Raw("readonly")) } })
```

Based on the success of this testing I implemented and tested it in several parts of my project.  Today I started on a new section of the code and commenced implementing the same code only to have it consistently fail - every control is `readonly`.

When I inspected the controls they either have `readonly` or `readonly=readonly` as the attribute?  I then went back to the code I refactored yesterday to find the same problem; every control is now `readonly` regardless of the value of `ViewBag.CanEdit`?

Can anyone explain why this would have worked yesterday but fails today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location, !ViewBag.CanEdit 
    ? (object)new { @class = "form-control", @readonly ="readonly" } 
    : (object)new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks Nitin, I have already commenced refactoring my code to use this code however I would really like to find out why the code in my example worked initially as I ended up wasting a lot of time on it.

Comment: Have updated accordingly. Its just that I have taken so called 'REFERNCE' from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086104/mvc3-conditionally-disable-html-textboxfor ;)

Answer (score 2):

As a better approach, I have created this method and I am using this in my project, whenever I need such thing. It will make your code much cleaner.

Firstly, add this class to your project:

```
 public static class HtmlBuildersExtended
    {
        public static RouteValueDictionary ConditionalReadonly(
            bool isReadonly,
            object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            var dictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

            if (isReadonly)
                dictionary.Add("readonly", "readonly");

            return dictionary;
        }
   }
```

Then you can change your code as:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location, 
      HtmlBuildersExtended.ConditionalReadonly(
          (bool)ViewBag.CanEdit, new { @class = "form-control" }));
```

Or if you want to use `EditorFor` helper, then:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location,
             HtmlBuildersExtended.ConditionalReadonly((bool)ViewBag.CanEdit, 
                    new
                    {
                        htmlAttributes = new
                        {
                            @class = "form-control"
                        }
                    }));
```