# How can I use the same partial view for input and output?

Tags: c#, razor

I have a partial view that I'm using for user input. I want to show the same partial view on a results page, but I want all of the input items to be readonly or disabled.

I know that I can use if-else syntax, but I really only want to set the readonly or disabled flag on the item, so duplicating the whole entity seems heavy handed and repetitive.

What I want is to be able to toggle between:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.inputValue, new {disabled="disabled", @id="one"})
```

and

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.inputValue, new {@id="one"})
```

or readonly, if that's easier to manipulate.

Based on other answers, I gather that this is discouraged due to the separation of concerns, but I hate the idea of having to maintain two files when one will do.

So, the question is: what is the proper syntax to use to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a Boolean `ViewBag` in the view, and set it when you render the view from the controller.

Check the value of this `ViewBag` when rendering these textboxes.

Comment: I know how to tell when to use which kind of entry, but I want to know what syntax I can use to do the job. I edited the question to make that clearer.

Comment: @wandercoder Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086104/mvc3-conditionally-disable-html-textboxfor

Comment: Beautiful. The example cleared it up for me. Thanks.