# How to disable a button more elegantly

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have on one of my views the following razor code:

```
@if (item.PMApproved != true) {
                    <input type="button" class="btnresetinvoice button" value="Reset" data-invoiceid="@item.InvoiceId" />
                }
                else {
                    <input type="button" class="btnresetinvoice button" value="Reset" data-invoiceid="@item.InvoiceId" disabled="disabled" />
                }
```

Pretty rough. Basically I want to disable the button under a certain condition as you'd be able to work out from the code. What would be a more desirable way of doing this?

Comment: What language is this (besides HTML)?

Comment: what could possibly be more desirable? What flaws do you see in your solution?

Comment: It's the [razor template engine](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) which allows C# scripting via `@` prefix.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know what language you're using, but you might be able to move your `if` statement closer to the actual different between the two lines:

```
<input type="button" class="btnresetinvoice button" value="Reset"
       data-invoiceid="@item.InvoiceId"
       @{ if(item.PMApproved != true) { 
             @:disabled="disabled" 
        } }
/>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be accepting the disabled part in the if statement. It says the name 'disabled' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @AnonyMouse - Fixed now thanks to Yogu. In the future, you should include the language in your question so people don't have to guess at the syntax.

Comment: I'm trying to use this in my code but the `@:` seems to be hiding the `}` in my code which causes a syntax error any ideas on that?

Comment: @Mykroft Maybe try putting the plaintext on its own line? Or just the `<% ... %>` syntax instead?

Comment: I ended up putting `this.write` instead. Not a big deal but you may want to recheck the code in your answer and make sure it works with the `/>` on the end there.

Comment: This didnt work for me (razor does not compile) - went with @David Grant solution below

Comment: I was able to get this to work by using a syntax similar to the one found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9399772/744014).

Comment: I find code like this is ok until you need to add a 2nd, 3rd and 4th class conditionally, too.

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

```
<button type="submit" disabled="@(!item.PMApproved)"></button>
```

Comment: Only solution on this page that works for me in `.Net Core 2.1`

Answer (score 22):

A markup-centric solution aided by a new extension method:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
   public static HtmlString DisabledIf(this HtmlHelper html, bool condition)
   {
      return new HtmlString(condition ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : "");
   }
}
```

In your views, reuse out the wazoo:

```
<button type="reset" @Html.DisabledIf(someCondition)>Clear Fields</button>
```

Nicely reusable, and the rendered markup is very clean with regards to whitespace:

```
<button type="reset" disabled="disabled">Clear Fields</button>
```

Comment: Great solution that really follows the spirit of the framework. Make sure you put the method in a namespace that MVC can see.

Comment: for .NET core use `IHtmlHelper`

Answer (score 5):

Using asp.net mvc5 razor:

```
@if(condition)
{
   <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#content">Details</button>
}
else
{
   <button disabled>Details</button>
}
```

It prevents attempting to enable button from DevTools, because razor not visible for DevTools

Answer (score 4):

`<input type="button" value="Reset" @{@((!item.PMApproved) ? null : new { disabled = "disabled" })}; />`

No need for that bloated code, just keep it simple :-)

Answer (score 3):

A helper could help:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ApproveButton(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, MyViewModel item)
    {
        var button = new TagBuilder("input");
        button.Attributes["type"] = "button";
        button.Attributes["value"] = "Reset";
        button.AddCssClass("btnresetinvoice");
        button.AddCssClass("button");
        button.Attributes["data-invoiceid"] = item.InvoiceId.ToString();
        if (item.PMApproved)
        {
            button.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
        }
        return new HtmlString(button.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.ApproveButton(item)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<button @(isEnabled ? null : "disabled")>Butt</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible easy way:

```
<input type="button" @(item.PMApproved ? "disabled" : "") />
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it elegantly:

```
<button type="button"
        class="save"
        onclick="doSomething()"
        style="@(hasValidationErrors ? "background-color:gray;cursor:default" : string.Empty)" @(hasValidationErrors ? "disabled" : string.Empty)
        title="@validationErrors"
        @{
            if (ViewModel.Property == true)
            {
                @:disabled="disabled"
            }
         }>
```

Notice `ViewModel.Property == true`... this will add the `disabled` attribute to the button ***only if*** that view model property holds true. If false, no `disabled` attribute will be present and as such the button will be enabled.