# MVC C# view is not allowing if statement in tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some code like:

```
<table class="invisibleforprint">
    <thead>
        <tr class="mainheader">
            <th>@Html.ActionLink("Invoice Number", "Index", new { sortOrder= ViewBag.NumberSortParm })</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td class="invoiceActions">
                <input type="button" class="btnresetinvoice button" value="Reset" data-invoiceid="@item.InvoiceId" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }</tbody>
</table>
```

Which compiled fine. I went and added an if statement in the input:

```
<table class="invisibleforprint">
    <thead>
        <tr class="mainheader">
            <th>@Html.ActionLink("Invoice Number", "Index", new { sortOrder= ViewBag.NumberSortParm })</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td class="invoiceActions">
                <input type="button" class="btnresetinvoice button" value="Reset" data-invoiceid="@item.InvoiceId" @{ if(item.PMApproved != true) { @:disabled="disabled" } } />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }</tbody>
</table>
```

It's giving the error '} expected'

Say what? I've added an equal amount of opening closing brackets.

Anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use helpers? That looks like an awful tag soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" class="btnresetinvoice button" value="Reset" data-invoiceid="@item.InvoiceId" @(item.PMApproved != true ? "disabled='disabled'" : "" ) />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" value="Reset" data-invoiceid="@item.InvoiceId" @(item.PMApproved ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : null) />
```

Or you can use `@if` with `<text>` tag:

```
<input type="button" value="Reset" data-invoiceid="@item.InvoiceId" @if(item.PMApproved) { <text>disabled="disabled"</text>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using curly braces around your if statement, you should be using normal brackets.

i.e.:

```
@( if(item.PMApproved != true) { @:disabled="disabled" } )
```

Can you give that a try?

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't seem to like it

Comment: Btw there is no need to compare boolean value with true/false. You can simply write `if(item.PMApproved) { ... }`

Comment: In this case I do because it is a nullable bool

Answer (score 0):

You could perform the following pornography (but please don't):

```
<input type="button" class="btnresetinvoice button" value="Reset" data-invoiceid="@item.InvoiceId" @Html.Raw(item.PMApproved ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : "") />
```

or use helpers as I [suggested you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10169746/29407):

```
@Html.ApproveButton(item)
```