# Adding disabled attribute to a button using Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a bool in my ViewModel called DisableNextButton and I would like to use it to disable a button in my view. I should add that this button lives inside an if statement.

Ultimately, I'm trying to add the disabled attribute when DisableNextButton is true.

Here's my unsuccessful implementation:

```
@if(true)
{
    <button type="button" @{ if (Model.DisableNextButton) { <text>disabled="disabled"</text> } } >Next</button>
}
```

I should note that this gives me a functioning enabled button.

Comment: *"unsuccessful implementation"* - What's unsuccessful about it?

Comment: @RowanFreeman he mentioned in the post that it always created an enabled button.

Comment: I need to have this button disabled when Model.DisableNextButton is true.  That's not happening with the code above.

Comment: I don't know what to suggest. The code works for me. [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rQEaNc)

Answer (score 8):

Translated from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166288/how-to-disable-a-button-more-elegantly):

```
<input type="button" value="Next" 
    @{
        if(Model.DisableNextButton)
        {
            @:disabled="disabled"
        }
    }
/>
```

Basically, the `<text>` tag is unnecessary, as this is not text, it's an HTML attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I'm getting compile errors when using @: (I'm getting } expected in line 1 column 1).  Would it matter that I'm nesting if statements in Razor?

Comment: Do you have it exactly as typed?  I don't have it open, so you may need to tweak it - line endings do matter in Razor, that's why I have it with a newline at the end.  If this doesn't work and you find a tweak that does please post it as a comment and I will fix my post.

Comment: No, I have everything on the same line.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  When I step through the code in my view, the `@disabled="disabled` line gets skipped over.  I verified this by putting a dummy line after in the same if statement and that gets hit.  Looks like the same thing is happening to the code in my original post.

Comment: `@:disabled="disabled"` must be  `@disabled="disabled"`

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with inline if:s to have / not have some html property. In the end i just went for the most basic. Mabey not the prettyes solution but it woorks.

```
@if (condition)
{
    <span id="true"></span>
}
else 
{
    <span id="false"></span>
}
```

After some small test this woorks aswell!

```
<span @(someBool ? "selected=selected" : "")>Cool </span>
```