# Razor conditional attribute not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

In a tag I want to conditionally output the style attribute, e.g.: `<li style="@styleVar" >...</li>`
When styleVar is null it should not be written by razor (just the supposed standard functionality in Razor 2), but for some strange reason it is outputted as `<li style="">...</li>`, while I expect `<li>...</li>`.

This is in a partial view. In a normal view it is working.
So is this a bug in partial views?

Anybody the same experience?

Comment: Assuming you're using MVC3 here, if you are able to upgrade to MVC4, then you get this behaviour for free: http://www.beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-razor-changes.html

Comment: I am using MVC4. Note that I said that I use Razor 2, which is included in MVC4.

Comment: It seems like razor is a bit picky about spaces here, i removed a whitespace between the attribute name and the '=' and it worked.

Answer (score 11):

This does not seem to work in partial views and for custom html attributes such as data-test="@test". This is not omitted, instead it still puts in the data-test="". So the MVC team has to fix this asap.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's deliberate if `data` attributes are not removed

Comment: "data-" can't use conditional attribute, you can find this reference in the source code

// First, determine if this is a 'data-' attribute (since those can't use conditional attributes)
            LocationTagged<string> name = nameSymbols.GetContent(Span.Start);
            bool attributeCanBeConditional = !name.Value.StartsWith("data-", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Comment: And I see that this is still the case today as of .Net 6 -- that assigning `null` for a `data-` attribute won't exclude the attribute from the element.  Can anyone explain to me *why* this is the behavior that they have implemented?

Answer (score 6):

If the `styleVar` is equal to `null` (not the `string.Empty`) mvc4 will automatically do this.

**Conditional attribute rendering**

If you have an attribute that might be null, in the past you've needed to do a null check to avoid writing out an empty attribute, like this:

```
<div @{if (myClass != null) { <text>class="@myClass"</text> } }>Content</div>
```

Now Razor is able to handle that automatically, so you can just write out the attribute. If it's null, the attribute isn't written:

```
<div class="@myClass">Content</div>
```

So if @myClass is null, the output is just this:

```
<div>Content</div>
```

Comment: Is this applicable to Html.Helpers as well?

Comment: if the value of the attribute is null, attribute will not render

Answer (score 1):

Don't see any error in your code: you "hard code" markup and vary only style value.
To achieve what you are trying to do, you need code similar to this:

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(styleVar))
{
  <li style="@styleVar" >...</li>
}
```

Comment: I expect <li>...</li> as output. Edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: According to your changes. If string evaluates to NULL it will remove empty attribute, but if string evaluates to empty string, it will render empty attribute. This is an algorithm of Razor v2

Comment: indeed, that work's for top level views, but seems not to work for partial views.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had a situation where a space between an attribute name and the equals sign broke boolean conditional rendering:

So

`<input type="checkbox" name="fieldname" id ="fieldname" checked="@Model.MyBool" />`

rendered with `checked="True"`, whereas

`<input type="checkbox" name="fieldname" id="fieldname" checked="@Model.MyBool" />`

rendered correctly with `checked="checked"`

The conditional rendering appears fairly brittle.

This isn't exactly an answer to the detail of the OP's question, but it's definitely a possibility for people who are looking for help with "Razor conditional attribute not working"

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is a Razor comment within the HTML tag.

```
// This renders <div>Hello world</div>
<div class="@null">Hello world</div>

// Renders <div  class="">Hello world</div>
<div @**@ class="@null">Hello world</div>
```

I ran into this when I had commented out a single attribute for testing purposes and all of the sudden my conditional attributes were broken.

Answer (score -1):

When `styleVar == null` you will get `<li style="">...` (at least with mvc3) in partial and normal views.

I guess you have to use the conditional operator:

```
<li @(styleVar == null ? "" : "style=\"" + styleVar + "\"")>...</li>
```

Comment: I am working with Razor 2, as I said in my question, which is used in MVC4. So this answer does not apply