# asp.net razor if syntax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm a beginner with ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to set the src of an image with razor in a asp.net MVC website using an If statement.

this code works :

```
 <img src="@Url.Action("GetPersonPhoto", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary( new { cardid = "696969" }) )" />
```

I want to add :

```
@if(Model.HavePhoto)
```

And set the src to :

```
"~/Content/images/header-logo.png"
```

if HavePhoto is false...

How can I do it ?

Comment: RT(F)M. Ok, to be serious...google any example. Image source itself shouldn't be IMO inside your cshtml page but decided in controller and stored in model src="@Model.PhotoUrl"

Comment: I would have the `GetPersonPhoto` action decide which image to use and handle cases where `Model.HavePhoto` are false, providing the url of a default image, as oppose to handle this in the view layer

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399531/asp-net-mvc-razor-conditional-attribute-in-html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061647/conditional-html-attributes-using-razor-mvc3 for couple options, you could also just have two different `img` tags, one in the if and one in an else for each case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var source= "~/Content/images/header-logo.png";
    @if(Model.HavePhoto)
    {
       source= Url.Action("GetPersonPhoto", "Home", 
                   new RouteValueDictionary( new { cardid = "696969" }))
    }

    <img src="@source" />
```

Comment: Depending on the context you probably need to wrap the variable declaration `@{ var source= "~/Content/images/header-logo.png"; }`

Comment: Thanks. I have a null reference exception with "@if(Model.HavePhoto)" but otherwise your solution seems to work.