# ASP.NET Core Razor: Conditional attribute without value

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I want to conditionally render a `readonly` attribute in an `<input>`. In the ASP.NET Core dialect of Razor the interpretation of attributes is a little different opposed to System.Web.Mvc.

In System.Web.Mvc I used to do:

```
<input name="Name" class="form-control" @(Model.MyCondition ? "readonly" : "") />
```

In ASP.NET Core, the same does not work: no error, but the attribute isn't rendered either.

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" @(Model.MyCondition ? "readonly" : "" ) />
```

Once the attribute is present in the HTML it is enforced, so I cannot do something with the *value* of the attribute. This snippet would cause the input to *always* be read-only:

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" readonly="@(Model.MyCondition ? "readonly" : "" )" />
```

Now, I can work around by creating a tag helper that would respond to the `is-readonly` tag, but that seems very convoluted for something so simple.

**How do I conditionally render a no-value attribute without resorting to a custom tag helper?**

Comment: I test in razor page it works on my side , when MyCondition  is true it shows the `readonly` attribute , could you please share the steps to reproduce ?

Comment: Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665997/5480409) to an answer of mine that solves the same problem, just omit the value part.

Answer (score 13):

If you set the value to `null` when your condition isn't matched (instead of an empty string) then the attribute will not be rendered, as follows:

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" readonly="@(Model.MyCondition ? "readonly" : null )" />
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. It still renders the "readonly" attribute without a value

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399531/asp-net-mvc-razor-conditional-attribute-in-html

Comment: This definitely works for me with ASP.NET Core 3.1; I even inspected the raw source to confirm. That said, I was using the `disabled` value instead of `readonly` (but they should work the same). I was also using the `asp-for` attribute, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Pluto This is strange because any `attribute="@(nullValuedVariable)"` renders `attribute=""` for me in .net core 3.1 mvc.

Comment: @Feri I wonder if it has to do with Razor compiling the page and only programming the behavior to skip outputting the attribute if there's an explicit null check. Did you try using a conditional expression instead of only outputting the variable? There's got to be some reason for this inconsistent behavior. I know doing `@(obj == null ? null : obj)` is stupid, but with ASP.NET it just might work LOL

Comment: this worked perfect in .net core 7 + MVC thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    var htmlAttributes = (MyModel.MyCondition == true) ? (object)new
    {
        @@readonly = "readonly"
    } : null;
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nom,  htmlAttributes)
```

Answer (score -1):

What I do is create an @if statement. I find it more transparent.

```
@if (Model.MyCondition)
{
  <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
}
else
{
  <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
}
```

Comment: I get you got downvoted because this doesn't answer the question exactly, but this is a simple way to accomplish what I needed and I was blinded by trying to force conditional attributes to be the solution like other front-end frameworks support when ASPNET Razor never had that feature as a first class citizen and everyone's answer is just an ugly hack.