# IIS express doesn't show index.cshtml in one folder but in other it shows

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with C# and .Net Framework 4.7.

I've just created a new ASP.NET MVC 5 controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TRZF.Web.API.Controllers
{
    public class ReportsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Reports
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I have right clicked at `Index` method and select `Add View...`. It has created a new `cshtml` file in folder `.\Views\Reports` called `Index.cshtml` with this content:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Resources.ReportsIndexTitle;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Styles
{
    <link href="~/css/tables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}

@section Body
{
    <div class="bodyBackground1">
        <div class="titulo">
            <h2>@Resources.ReportsIndexHeader</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="formPO">

        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>@Resources.ViewGenericInvConCopyright</p>
        </div><!-- end .footer -->
    </div>
}

@section scripts
{
}
```

I use this to navigate to that file:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Resources.GetReports, "Index", "Reports")
```

But I have added a breakpoint at `ReportsController.Index` method and it doesn't stop.

I have a lot of more Controllers working and I did the same with them that I've done know but this one doesn't work. All of them works perfectly, showing their index page and stopping at `Index` method but when I try this one I get a screen with `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden`.

What's going on?

Comment: I can't believe that someone with 16K worth of reputation asked such a question... Have you changed the default routing? If yes, how? Show us some code! What is the exception thrown? I.e. what gets displayed in the browser, after you follow your link?

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev I can not believe someone criticizes instead of asking for more information. Do you try to help or criticize? I have a lot of more Controllers working and I did the same with them that I've done know but this one doesn't work.

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev, *Have you changed the default routing?* that's not needed if you are using the full URL, routing will get that resolved

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev, *I can't believe that someone with 16K worth of reputation asked such a question* why not? He may be new to MVC all-together. Right?

Comment: I understand the situation of @VansFannel.. As Rahul said he is knew to MVC

Comment: @Rahul _He may be new to MVC all-together_ Right. But didn't relieve him from the fact to know how SO works, right? He must have got these reputation somehow. I'm pretty sure he knows how to ask questions here, regardless of his domain of expertise... Don't you all be mad, I'm just pointing out the obvious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause for your `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden` error is that you also have a folder in your app named `Reports` so its attempting to navigate to your folder, rather than your controller method.

If so rename that folder to anything other than the name of one of your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

> But I have added a breakpoint at ReportsController.Index method and it
>   doesn't stop.

Since it's deployed in IIS, just setting an breakpoint won't enough, you will have to attach the `w3wp` worker process to the debugger in-order to debug.

How to attach an external process to VS debugger?

See MSDN for more information.

Comment: My problem here is: I have a lot of more Controllers working and I did the same with them that I've done know but this one doesn't work.

Comment: @VansFannel, doesn't work is too broad .. narrow it down what doesn't work and how you tried?

Comment: I have a lot of more Controllers working and I did the same with them that I've done know but this one doesn't work. All of them works perfectly, showing their index page and stopping at Index method but when I try this one I get a screen with HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.

Comment: @VansFannel, do you have any `Area` defined for this one?

Comment: No, I don't have any `Area` defined.