# cast to a variable type

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

Is it possible to cast from a Dynamic or an Object to a variable type? The target variable type is one generic class, only the specific data type varies.

I'm looking for abstract solution, but the situation is this: I want a single Linq2SQL command for different Entities - I can GetProperty + GetValue of the EntityFramework Context, but then it must be casted to some exact types, but these come from variable input - names of DB tables.

Example of what I have:

```
 Type NewType = typeof(System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<>);
 NewType.MakeGenericType(new Type[] {"...some type here that's variable accordint to user input - like Person, Address, Contact, ..."});            
 Object MyObject = Context.GetType().GetProperty("the same variable like above - Person, Address,...", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(Context, null); // this is EntityFramework Context
```

Example of what I need but don't know how to do it:

```
 NewType CastedObject = (NewType) MyObject;
 // or
 NewType CastedObject = Convert.ChangeType(MyObject, NewType);
 // or
 NewType CastedObject = MyObject as NewType;
```

so I could do this:

```
 (from x in CastedObject where x.ID == ID select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

For those, who are familiar with PHP, I'm trying to do this:

```
 (from x in Context.$tablename where x.ID == ID select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `NewType` is a runtime type, how could you have a variable of compile-time type `NewType`? The compiler must know the "declared" type of all variables. So what you want is not possible.

Something you *can* do is cast `MyObject` to `dynamic`. Then stuff like `foreach (var x in CastedToDynamic)` would compile (but no compile-time type checking).

You can't use LINQ on a `dynamic` expression, though. You will have to rewrite like:

```
    dynamic found = null;
    foreach (var x in CastedToDynamic)
    {
      if (x.ID == ID)
      {
        found = x;
        break;
      }
    }
```

Note: Which overload of `==` to use will be decided at run-time. So even if `ID` is a (boxed) `System.Guid`, say, the `==` will (unbox and) call the overload of `==` defined inside that struct. So this works.

Comment: Even if the NewType is declared in the EF, but only "dynamically chosen" by variable?

Comment: @JanMatousek (Your first comment) There's no chance you can declare a variable of a "non-fixed" type. The closest you get is generic types. But it won't help when you construct the type from "user input". Generic types are still compile-time types, for example with `void MyMethod<T>(T arg) { ... }` the type `T` is bound compile-time. So no luck.

Comment: This solution works! 
foreach(var x in (dynamic)CastedObject) {...}
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might get at what you are looking at (relies heavily on reflection)

```
        List<dynamic> mylist = new List<dynamic>();
        dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
        data.Foo = "foo";
        data.ID = 1;
        mylist.Add(data);

        data = new ExpandoObject();
        data.Foo = "foobar";
        data.ID = 2;
        mylist.Add(data);


        data = new ExpandoObject();
        data.Foo = "foobar2";
        data.ID = 2;
        mylist.Add(data);

        data = new ExpandoObject();
        data.Foo = "foobar2";
        data.ID = 3;
        mylist.Add(data);

        int idiminterestedin = 2;

        var dynamicselected = mylist.Select(d=>((IDictionary<string,object>)d)).Where(d=>
        {
            object id;
            if (d.TryGetValue("ID",out id))
            {
                return (id is int) && (int)id == idiminterestedin;
            }
            return false;
        });

        foreach (var v in dynamicselected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v["Foo"]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Though I'd probably skip the ExpandoObject and go straight for a dictionary:

```
        Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        data["Foo"] = "foo";
        data["ID"] = 1;
```

And then make a generic extension function(s):

```
static class ExptensionFunction
{
    static T GetValueAs<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> obj, string key)
    {
        return (T)obj[key];
    }

    static bool TryGetValueAs<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> d, string key, out T value)
    {
        object id;
        if (d.TryGetValue(key, out id))
        {
            if (id is T)
            {
                value = (T)id;
                return true;
            }
        }

        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> GetValuesWithKey<T>(this List<Dictionary<string, object>> list, string key, T value)
    {
        return list.Where(d =>
        {
            T id;
            if (d.TryGetValueAs<T>(key, out id))
            {
                return id.Equals(value);
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Inspired by this:

[Creating an anonymous type dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024754/creating-an-anonymous-type-dynamically)

and

[Add property to anonymous type after creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233711/add-property-to-anonymous-type-after-creation)